# How to bind Vue js watchers to an array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array that contains many objects like this :

> [{x:  updateX}, {y: updateY} ]

By using this array, I want to generate Vue js watchers automatically like this:

```
      watch: {
     x(){
         this.updateX()
       },
     y(){
         this.updateY()
       }
 }
```

I only know that vue keep watchers as array.

Comment: Hey, I don't really get the need. You want to bind watchers to all your array objects ?

Comment: Yes. I will change the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create an array and return from it a list of functions something like this:

```
data(){ return {
  watcherArray: [];
}
}
methods: {
   pushToWatchersArray() {
      this.watcherArray.push(someValue);
    }
    returnNewWatchers(){
       return { this.watchersArray.map(watcher => return `${watcher}(){ 
       this.updatewatcher()}
    }
watch: {
    [...this.returnNewWatchers()]
 }
```

You may also need to rerender the component when changing the watchers, I am not sure about this, in addition you may need a separate watcher to watch for changes on the array to do this rerender.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a deep watcher for that

```
watch: {
  arr: {
     handler(val){
       // do stuff
     },
     deep: true
  }
}
```